# Detecting imminent screen off and intercepting it on Android

Tags: android, screen

I would like to create a program that tracks a users eye focus when the screen is about to go off and then depending on where the user focus is the screen will be allowed to turn off or remain on. To do this, I need to find a way of, per say, intercepting screen off commands. Does anyone know of a proper, superficial method of doing this so I don't need to dig deep into the ecosystem?

Answer (score 1):

This may be of use:

http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/

Note that this applies to the activity lifecycle, which means it only has meaning for a 1) visible activity that 2) has user focus. It sounds like you're trying to make a background service, and that would be *much* trickier. This isn't really something that was designed to be hooked into, especially for arbitrary apps that are not your own.

Comment: Ah, thank you. This looks promising. I'll be sure to check it out and report back if it works out.